# Как изменить тэг у объекта внутри префаба?

Tags: c#, unity3d, prefabs

У меня есть префаб, состоящий из трёх платформ. Одна из этих платформ - это платформа, которая выполняет условие при прикосновении с игроком. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда игрок(other) и объект с тегом PlatformGo соприкасались - у объекта(PlatformGo, это название) в префабе менялся тэг. Но, так как этот объект внутри префаба, в публичную переменную я его закинуть не могу.

Вот мой код:

```
public GameObject Platform;
public GameObject PlatformGo;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "PlatformGo")
        {
            if (PlatformTotal == 0 && PlatformSpawned == false)
            {
                PlatformGo.gameObject.tag = "Platform";
            }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Platform - это переменная GameObject, в которую вставлен префаб.

PlatformGo - это переменная GameObject. Если наступить на объект с тегом "PlatformGo", то его тег должен смениться на "Platform", но так как я не знаю, как засунуть объект из префаба в скрипт, ничего не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл другой способ решения данной проблемы, не используя инспектор. Для этого нужно вставить в начало функции `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)` следующую строку:

```
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "PlatformGo")
        {
            GameObject Go = other.gameObject; //Создание
            if (PlatformTotal == 0 && PlatformSpawned == false)
            {
                PlatformGo.gameObject.tag = "Platform";
                Go.gameObject.tag = "Platform"; //Смена
            }
        }
```